# How to change the bootstrap css width into 1000px?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap container width is fixed in 1170px, I would like to convert the 
container width into 1000. So, please any one can answer me and also tell me the procedure.

Comment: Any attempt to try it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

CSS override:

```
body .container {
    width: 100%; !important;
}
```

Or to a fixed width:

```
body .container {
    width: 1000px; !important;
}
```

But if you use `bootstrap-responsive`, you will lose the reponsiveness so you will need to configure those too in your CSS declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is add another css file after bootstrap-responsive in your html header, with the rule:

```
body .container {
    width: 1000px; !important;
}
```

an each other bootstrap style you want to overryde

Answer (score -2):

you can specify simply `style="width:1000px;"`  for that div